# Error de Hibernate al intentar usar la libreria ControlsFx

Tags: java, javafx, hibernate, autocompletar

Lo que quiero intentar es que al escribir algo en mi textfield este se auto-complete con información de mi Base de Datos

Aquí Declaro el La caja de texto que quiero que haga el auto completado

```
@FXML
private TextField txtGeneracion;
```

Clase java RegistroAlumno.

```
  autocomplete service = new autocomplete();



    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(txtGeneracion, t-> {

        return service.getSuggestions("code", t.getUserText());

    });
```

Clase de java auto-complete.

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

```
    public List<String> getSuggestions(String fieldName, String searchString) {


        List<String> list = null;

        HibernateUtil.openSession().getSessionFactory().close();;

        Session s = HibernateUtil.openSession().getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {

            s.beginTransaction();

            Query query = s.createQuery("select Generacion from alumno");

            list = query.setParameter("search", "%"+searchString+"%").setMaxResults(10).list();

            s.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");

        } finally {

            s.close();

        }       

        return list;

    }
```

Nota: Estoy usando una librería que se llama ControlsFx de Java es .jar y ya lo tengo agregado a la librería

Error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de que escribo algo que existe en la base de datos me marca esas lineas rojas y nada mas no me hace el efecto de auto completar.

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede que te sirva, échale un vistazo. http://kaykovus.blogspot.com.es/2015/01/how-to-use-controlsfx-autocomplete.html

Comment: Muchas Gracias, ya lo habia localizado je